# Get text before and after br/ tag - htmlagilitypack in vb.net

Tags: html, vb.net, selectsinglenode

How can I get the text in this HTML block?

```
<td align="left" style="">2000000033754<br/>CHOICE_HARVEST-GALA _APPLE-10S</td>
```

I am using HTMLAgilityPack, this is my code in vb.net

```
If cols1(m).OuterHtml.Contains("<br>") Then
   ' split into barcode and item name
   Dim barcode As HtmlNode = cols1(m).SelectSingleNode("text()[preceding::br]")
   sSQL = sSQL & "," & ToCHR(barcode.InnerText.Trim)
   Dim item As HtmlNode = cols1(m).SelectSingleNode("text()[following::br]")
   sSQL = sSQL & "," & ToCHR(item.InnerText.Trim)
```

I need to get these results

`barcode.innertext = "2000000033754"` - this is working

`item.innertext = "CHOICE_HARVEST-GALA _APPLE-10S"` - NEED HELP WITH THIS

Answer (score 0):

If you know this is the structure, you can simply use the fact that HtmlAgilityPack will split the nodes between HtmlNode and TextNode. In the following example, the `li` contains three children: two text elements (`before` and `after`) separated by a html element (`br`)

```
var hd = new HtmlDocument();
hd.LoadHtml("<html><body><ul><li>before<br/>after</li></ul></body></html>");
var lis = hd.DocumentNode.FirstChild.FirstChild.FirstChild; // select the ul
foreach (var li in lis.ChildNodes)
{
    var firstTextNode = li.ChildNodes.First(hn => hn.NodeType == HtmlNodeType.Text);
    var lastTextNode = li.ChildNodes.Last(hn => hn.NodeType == HtmlNodeType.Text);
}
```